# DTO bool field false (vs. true) triggers WriteStartElement can be called at only the start of a document or immediately after calling WriteEndElement?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest, json.net

Very bizarre. From a WCF REST client (not a service):

I'm getting "WriteStartElement can be called at only the start of a document or immediately after calling WriteEndElement" in a WCF client when a DTO parameter field value is set to "false" vs. "true". That's it. Just a bool field in the object. Why on earth should that make a difference?

Has anyone seen this before? Lots of methods with various objects work just fine. And this method works just fine, with the same DTO. All that triggers this is a false bool value on a property. *mind blown*

This occurs after both the 'SerializeRequest' and 'BeforeSendRequest' WCF extensibility points (methods). The Message object is created successfully, and everything seems like it 'should' work. Baffled.

Here is the simple property (of which there are many, that work fine). Nothing special here!

```
[DataMember(Name="addToInventory")]
public bool AddToInventory
{
    get
    {
        return this.m_addToInventory;
    }
    set
    {
        this.m_addToInventory = value;
    }
}
```

The object is serialized (into Json) by Json.Net, converted to a Byte array, and then used to construct a WCF message. That part works fine. Once it gets down into the channel, something weird is happening.

A brief snippet of that step (works perfectly everywhere, except for this one object, where this one field is set to a false value).

```
byte[] jsonObjectsByteArray = { };

foreach (var parameter in parameters)
{
    string jsonSerializedParam = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameter);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonSerializedParam))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    byte[] paramByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonSerializedParam);

    if (paramByteArray.Length != 0)
    {
        jsonObjectsByteArray = jsonObjectsByteArray.Concat(paramByteArray).ToArray();
    }
}

// Read the Json Byte array into a JsonReader 
// >This is the message body<
var jsonToWcfInfoSetReader = 
    JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(
        jsonObjectsByteArray,
        0,
        jsonObjectsByteArray.Length,
        XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);

// Position on an element
jsonToWcfInfoSetReader.MoveToStartElement();

// Create the WCF message
apiCallMsg = Message.CreateMessage(
    messageVersion,
    m_operation.Messages[0].Action,
    jsonToWcfInfoSetReader);
```

Comment: Can you create a short demo program to reproduce the problem and post it in your question?

Comment: Hi Brian, there are 200 DTOs that all work (including this one). It is literally just a true vs. false value on a property (where there are other bool properties, etc., that work fine). Wild, huh? Across this broad API I cannot reproduce it anywhere. I've posted the property above.